# How to convert a string taken from the web with beautifulSoup into a text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, nltk

i'm pretty new in python 3 coding, and i need help with beautiful soup module.
When i take the text from an html page with get_text(), it returns a single Unicode string that I can't analize with nltk methods, such as mystring.concordance(), len(mystring) etc.

Is there any method to convert the string into a txt that I can than analize?

```
import nltk, bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from html.parser import HTMLParser

adress= input()
html = requests.get(adress)

testo = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml").get_text("|")
testo.concordance("politics")
```

running this it reports an "AttributeError-: 'str' object has no attribute 'concordance'

Comment: For some reason it cut the first part of the msg with "Hi everyone", sorry.

Comment: Similarly, "Thanks in advanced." is (1) unnecessary fluff, and (2) bad grammar.

Comment: @Sumurai8, ok thanks I didn't know that. I thought I came out quite rude as forums generally have rules about this sort of stuff.

Comment: @RadLexus, commenting on (1) unnecessary fluff, and (2) bad grammar, when english is clearly not my mother language, is irrelevant fluff as well tbh.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a "forum" (and it's considered quite rude to refer to it as such). It's also not surprising you don't know the rules when you were offered to take an introductory [tour] and decided, "nah, who cares".